# ViewPager not displaying all fragments - only visible when tapped

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Fragment visibility problem inside in ViewPager

I have a ViewPager, inside this multiple fragment associated and all fragment creating by for loop according to fragment list size.
All fragment is attached with ViewPager and completed of all fragment funtionality but visible only when i tap on unvisible fragment.

Code is below

```
//This is FragmentStatePagerAdapter
 ViewPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        boolean isShowLoader = false;
        if (!isFromGroup || isTotalAddedInGroup) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mainList.size(); i++) {
                BranchesList branchesList = mainList.get(i);
                String comType = branchesList.getCompanyType();
                if (comType != null && !comType.equalsIgnoreCase("W")) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    if (branchesList.toDate == null || isBeforeFy(branchesList.toDate)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                GroupItemFragment itemFragment=  getGroupItemReportFragment(branchesList, !isShowLoader && i == 0);
                if (itemFragment==null){
                    continue;
                }
                pagerAdapter.addFragment(itemFragment);
            }
        }else {
            pagerAdapter.addFragment(getGroupItemReportFragment(branchesList, false));
        }
        newViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
```

What is i going to wrong plz tell me

Answer (score 0):

This is the working principle of Viewpager. It works with the preload system.

> Just call setOffscreenPageLimit() in onCreate() (after initializing
> ViewPager). The OffscreenPageLimit sets the number of pages that
> should be retained to either side of the current page (in your case
> 2). With this all of your fragments will be instantiate.
>
> (An other (highly recommended) possibility is to increase the
> performance of your lists or listadapters, because a loading time of 2
> seconds doesn't sound good)

Edit 2 : Using FragmentStateAdapter.

```
class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(fa: FragmentActivity) : FragmentStateAdapter(fa) {
    override fun getItemCount(): Int = NUM_PAGES

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment = SampleFragment()
}
```

Comment: page limit is not know in advance

Comment: Problem is need to tap on screen to visible fragment inside ViewPager'